# Google sheets update values based on current month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

[image]I need help with Google Sheets.

Basically, i want to detect the currfent month and display its name and corresponding value on a cell.

this is the link:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JCApwNgftzR0nCCMh5Uyd_6aX0Z29Kjt0T40Lpu9Puo/edit?usp=sharing

i need to have the 'sales target' displayed automatically based on the current months sales target.  Same for the profit.  I need to the current months profit automatically updating deppending on which month were on.

Im very new to google sheets, if anyone can help me i would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your file with these formulas:

**current month name**:

```
=text(today(), "mmmm")
```

**Sales target for the current month**:

```
=Vlookup( eomonth(today(),-1)+1,B11:C,2,false)
```

**Total profit up to the current month**:

```
= sumif(B11:B, "<=" & eomonth(today(),-1)+1, E11:E)
```